# Comments on answer keep getting removed

Tags: support, deleted-comments

I recently answered a question on the Interpersonal Skills site. I have an email digest for activity and keep getting alerts for comments on my answer, but when I check on the web version of the site a little time later there are no comments to view.

The answer (and a comment ID) is [How to get my coworkers and family to respect my hobby](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/8523/how-to-get-my-coworkers-and-family-to-respect-my-hobby/8525?noredirect=1#comment33078_8525)

If someone could let me know why seemingly harmless comments on my answer are constantly being removed then I’d be grateful, as I’d like to know if I’ve done something wrong and what to avoid in the future.

Answer (score 8):

As Robert mentioned on your [Meta Stack Exchange question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305287/comments-on-answer-keep-getting-removed#comment992271_305287):

> Martin, comments are meant to ask for clarification or otherwise make suggestions to improve a post... and then removed when they serve that purpose. Comments are not meant for answers or to host permanent information or extended discussion. But rather than relying on that generic guidance, I suggest you ask on interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com so the folks who took those actions can provide more insight about your case specifically.

There are eight deleted comments on your answer:

[image: Comments on Martin Bean's Answer]

Comment 1 (by user6014) is a joke and adds nothing to the answer. Comments 2 and 3 are responses to user6014's comment and, again, add nothing to the answer. All three comments were flagged and removed.

Comments 4, 5, and 8 all say the same thing and are encouraging discussion. If you find their point valuable, feel free to edit your answer but three comments saying the same thing are unnecessary and if you either choose not to add the information to your answer or you do, none of them are useful.

Comment 6 was from a user, "coinbird" and 7 was your response to it, pointing out that the comment wasn't correct about your answer, so both were deleted and obsolete after being flagged.

I've reinstated comment 4 as being an actual *question* to improve the answer rather than the other two which are comments that don't suggest improvement or ask for clarification. Though, these comments relate to your specific example and have little relevance to the question about model trains. Whether or not wrestling is real compared to other hobbies like watching other fictional productions is relevant only to the discussion of wrestling.